# How do you use RegisterFactory?

Tags: c#, unity-container

I am having problems understanding how to use `RegisterFactory`.  The code below works fine with the older `InjectionFactory` but I am having problems when I try to do the same thing with `RegisterFactory`.

In the sample code there is an uncommented section that uses `RegisterFactory` and a commented section that uses `InjectionFactory`.  The `InjectionFactory` code works fine but the RegisterFactory throws a `ResolutionFailedException`.

Unity.ResolutionFailedException: 'The current type, ConsoleApp1.IFoo, is an interface and cannot be constructed. Are you missing a type mapping?'

What am I doing incorrectly?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var container = new UnityContainer();
        container.EnableDebugDiagnostic();

        container.RegisterType<IFoo, Foo1>("Foo1");
        container.RegisterType<IFoo, Foo2>("Foo2");

        container.RegisterType<MainViewModel>();

        // This does not work
        container.RegisterFactory<Func<string, IFoo>>((c, type, name) => c.Resolve<IFoo>(name));

        // This works
        //container.RegisterType<Func<string, IFoo>>(new InjectionFactory(
        //    ctx => new Func<string, IFoo>(name => container.Resolve<IFoo>(name))));


        var vm = container.Resolve<MainViewModel>();
    }
}

public class MainViewModel
{
    public MainViewModel(Func<string, IFoo> fooFactory)
    {
        var foo1 = fooFactory.Invoke("Foo1");
        var foo2 = fooFactory.Invoke("Foo2");
    }
}

public interface IFoo
{
    string Name { get; }
}

public class Foo1 : IFoo
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Foo1()
    {
        Name = "Foo1";
    }
}

public class Foo2 : IFoo
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Foo2()
    {
        Name = "Foo2";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're registering with `RegisterFactory`, you tell *Unity* how to construct the instance. But Unity already knows how to construct `Foo1` and `Foo2`, because you registered those already.

What you want is a factory for *you* to use, that's what `RegisterType` does, so this works.

Normally, such a factory would implement some `IFooFactory`, thus making the context more obvious. But as long as `Func<string, IFoo>` is registered only used once, it works fine, too, of course.

Comment: Hi Haukinger, thanks for responding but I am confused about your answer.  I am trying to convert the code that uses the InjectionFactory to use RegisterFactory since it is marked obsolete.  I want to create multiple Foo1 and Foo2 objects based on user interactions (passing in a string name).   I thought the lambda expression is providing the FooFactory.

Comment: exactly, but you need to register the lambda as foofactory for your consumers, not as factory for unity to use (because unity does not need it, because it cannot use it anyway, because it does not know the string parameter)

Comment: The following worked: container.RegisterFactory<Func<string, IFoo>>(c => new Func<string, IFoo>(name => c.Resolve<IFoo>(name)));